# HaProxy randomly returning 503 for static files when servers are available

Tags: proxy, http, haproxy

HaProxy is randomly returning 503 even though there definitely are backend servers available. The backend is serving the files correctly, as it's access log shows it *always* returning a 200 or 304. I'm scratching my head why this is happening. The weirdist thing is it's *only* happening on this css file!

Example 503 Log Message:

> Oct  3 17:26:24 haproxy0-1 haproxy[2313]: x.x.x.x:53265 [03/Oct/2018:17:26:24.187] https-in~ appName/apps-1.prod.companyName.com 0/0/-1/-1/1 503 213 - - CC-- 22/22/16/8/0 0/0 {|} "GET /appName/resources/css/appName.css HTTP/1.1"

HaProxy config:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!AES256
    ssl-default-bind-options force-tlsv12
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    lua-load /etc/haproxy/cors.lua

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    timeout http-request 20000
    timeout queue 20000
    timeout connect 20000
    timeout client 20000
    timeout server 20000
    timeout http-keep-alive 20000
    timeout check 500
    maxconn 3000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend https-in
    bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/prod.companyName.com.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    capture request header origin len 128
    capture request header access-control-request-headers len 128
    http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin %[capture.req.hdr(0)] if !METH_OPTIONS { capture.req.hdr(0) -m reg -f /etc/haproxy/cors-origins.lst }
    http-request use-service lua.cors-response if METH_OPTIONS { capture.req.hdr(0) -m reg -f /etc/haproxy/cors-origins.lst }
    acl acl_appName path_beg /appName if !METH_OPTIONS
    use_backend appName if acl_appName
    default_backend no-match

backend appName
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    balance leastconn
    option httpchk GET /appName/haproxy.jsp HTTP/1.0
    server apps-1.prod.companyName.com apps-1.prod.companyName.com:8443 check ssl verify required ca-file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/companyName-CA.crt
    server apps-3.prod.companyName.com apps-3.prod.companyName.com:8443 check ssl verify required ca-file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/companyName-CA.crt

backend no-match
    http-request deny deny_status 404

listen stats
    bind localhost:9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /stats
    #stats admin if TRUE
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are probably requests from Firefox with RCWN ("Race Cache With Network") enabled:

"CC--" shows that the client aborted before the connection could be established to the backend-server, which happens when Firefox sends the HTTP request to haproxy and then immediately closes the connection (because it found the response in its cache).

Firefox [nsHttpChannel.cpp](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/152993fa346c8fd9296e4cd6622234a664f53341/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpChannel.cpp#3932):

```
// We will attempt to race the network vs the cache if we've found
// this entry in the cache index, and it has appropriate attributes
// (doesn't have alt-data, and has a small size)
```

See also [about:networking#rcwn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndSbb.png) (on Firefox)